# Price approximation of European call option using the explicit finite difference method in python not working

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to approximate the European call option price of the Black-Scholes model (PDE) by the explicit finite difference method in python. For reference, the exact solution using the Black-Scholes formula is 10.247013813310648

Here is a link about the PDE [Black-Scholes Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation) and the discretized version of the equation can be found here [Explicit finite difference method for Black-Scholes model](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/C-Explicit-Euler-Finite-Difference-Method-for-Black-Scholes/)

Can anyone point out why I'm not getting an approximation?

```
import numpy as np
# Terminal time
T = 0.25

# Strike price
K = 10

# risk free rate
r = 0.1

# volatility (systemic/market risk)
sigma = 0.4

# initial asset value
S0 = 20

# Assume an upper limit for the underlying stock that is 3 - 4 times the exercise price
S_max = 3 * K

# Number of space intervals
M = 200

# space mesh and space step
space_mesh, space_step  = np.linspace(0, S_max, M, retstep=True)

# Stability condition
stability_cond = 1 / ( sigma**2 * (M-1) + 0.5* r )

# Find the number of time intervals and time steps that satisfy the stability condition

for percentage in np.arange(.99, .0001, -.0001):
  time_step = np.round(percentage * stability_cond, 6)
  N = T / time_step
  if N.is_integer():
    print("Number of time intervals = ", N,"        ", "time step = ",  time_step)

# Choose number of time intervals
N = 2000

# time mesh
time_mesh, time_step = np.linspace(0, T, N, retstep= True)

# time step
time_step = np.round(time_step, 6)

# unknown u at new time level
u = np.zeros(M)

# u at the previous time level
u_prev = np.zeros(M)

# initial condition
for m in range(0, M):
  u_prev[m] = np.maximum(space_mesh[m] - K, 0)

# Explicit finite difference scheme
for n in range(0, N):
  for m in range(1,M-1):

    a = 0.5 *  time_step * ( sigma**2 *m**2  - r * m )
    b = 1 - time_step * ( sigma**2 * m**2  + r )
    c =  0.5 * time_step * ( sigma**2 * m**2  + r * m)
    
    # The discretized version of the Black-Scoles PDE
    u[m] = a * u_prev[m-1] + b* u_prev[m] + c * u_prev[m+1]

  # insert boundry conditions

  u[0] = 0

  u[M-1] = S_max

  # update u_prev before next iteration
  u_prev[:] = u
```